# Django deep admin.TabularInline

Tags: python, django, django-admin

if there is relation like: [image: UML1]

```
B.ForeignKey(A)
```

django can show it in `one` admin `page` by `TabularInline`:

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp2 import models
# Register your models here.
class TabularInlineB(admin.TabularInline):
    model=models.B

class AdminA(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines=[TabularInlineB, ]

admin.site.register(models.A, AdminA)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class A(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10)

class B(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    a=models.ForeignKey(A)
```

.the output is like:[image: output1]

but if we `add` another `ForeignKey` relation to `B`  like below,
[image: UML2]

```
B.ForeignKey(A)
C.ForeignKey(B)
```

then **How I can show all models in `one admin page`?**

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp2 import models

class TabularInlineC(admin.TabularInline):
    model=models.C

class TabularInlineB(admin.TabularInline):
    model=models.B
    inlines=[TabularInlineC, ]

class AdminA(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines=[TabularInlineB, ]

admin.site.register(models.A, AdminA)
```

.**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class A(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10)

class B(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    a=models.ForeignKey(A)

class C(models.Model):
    b=models.ForeignKey(B)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

the output dose not show C:[image: outpu2]

Comment: I don't think this is available out of the box, but there is a project that does this sort of thing: https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I managed to do it. I don't know if it's exactly what you need but let me know if it's not I'll remove my answer.

You can do it like that:

**Admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp2 import models

class TabularInlineC(admin.TabularInline):
    model=models.C

class TabularInlineB(admin.TabularInline):
    model=models.B      

class AdminA(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines=[TabularInlineB, TabularInlineC ]

admin.site.register(models.A, AdminA)
```

That will render two inlines having each a section in the admin page of model A. Note that in this code, both model B and Model C have foreign key to model A. Indeed, this is not exactly the same pattern you are using in your question but it is, in my opinion, the simplest way of achieving what you want. The fact that you point two models to the same, allow you to consider this Model has the ***parent model***. So, if you can find a common field to point to, you will be able to add two inlines in the same form since both models will have a link to Model A.

Also, another interesting thing you can do is add `classes = ['collapse']` to both  `class TabularInlineB` and `class TabularInlineC` this will allow collapsable on those two sections of your admin page.

Hope it helps !

**EDIT**

If you absolutely need to render only one inline that include both models, I'm also not sure if it is possible out of the box with Django.

Comment: Dose not work: ERRORS:
<class 'myapp.admin.TabularInlineC'>: (admin.E202) 'myapp.C' has no ForeignKey to 'myapp.A'.

Comment: I didn't notice your Model C had a foreign key to Model B. But is this mandatory ? Is it too late ? Because the way I see it is if you want every model in the same form you need to have a main model to point to. In this case, probably Model A. It worked just fine for me.

Comment: If you can still revert this behavior I'd propose you do it. Because if you don't, I'm not you'll acheive what you want.

Comment: please explain in the post

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but this is not my case.